# Getting 401 HTTP Unauthorised for file under _layouts/15

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, layouts

Attempting to retrieve a file from Sharepoint using guidance from this page

**https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest**

generally works.

I can access these types of files programmatically(download them locally):
 **"server/sites/site/folder/subfolder/myfile.xlsx"**

However:
**"server/sites/site/folder/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=entry&file=myfile.xlsx"**

has beeen annoyingly inaccessible for me - all I get is:

**HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized**

I can access the file in my browser without any issues. What am I missing here? I cannot find any references in the documentation nor online on what else to try here.

It is a requirement that I retrieve this file with a REST request and to download them locally.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**:

I personally prefer to pass this work to sharepoint and use the url something like below:

```
http://spsite/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://spsite/Documents/sample.docx
```

**Solution 2**:

You can set the binaryStringResponseBody to true to downstream a file from SharePoint.

```
var info = {
    url: appwebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Test/Shared Documents/" + sourcefile.get_name() + "')/$value?@target='myhosturl'",

    binaryStringResponseBody: true,
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function () { alert('error'); }

}
```

If you're facing any issue please follow the below link:
[Get file using REST in SharePoint 2013/Office 365](http://www.techmikael.com/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html).

**Solution 3**:

If you’re using SharePoint add-in/app, you could get file binary data by REST api.

```
_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Doc1/Lee1.docx')/$value
```

**Source**: [How to download file from document Library using Rest API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7f1cb7d-4406-4b72-b7f1-dc5dde6c34e1/how-to-download-file-from-document-library-using-rest-api).